# Unable to connect to MongoDB...the following error is showing

Tags: java, mongodb, database-replication

We are trying to connect to our Mongo replica set through our app servers.
We are facing this issue from some of app servers.
These app servers jvm log showing following issue. The following error message is shown from all members of replica set.

Getting NullPointerException while connecting :

```
    Aug 10, 2016 2:51:43 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
        INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server x.x.x.1:27017
        java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:53)
            at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:37)
            at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.getCodec(RequestMessage.java:245)
            at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.addDocument(RequestMessage.java:205)
            at com.mongodb.connection.CommandMessage.encodeMessageBodyWithMetadata(CommandMessage.java:75)
            at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.encodeWithMetadata(RequestMessage.java:160)
            at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.encode(RequestMessage.java:147)
            at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.sendMessage(CommandHelper.java:88)
            at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32)
            at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:187)
            at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:135)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 


Aug 10, 2016 2:51:45 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
        INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server x.x.x.2:27017
        java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:53)
            at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:37)
            at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.getCodec(RequestMessage.java:245)
            at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.addDocument(RequestMessage.java:205)
            at com.mongodb.connection.CommandMessage.encodeMessageBodyWithMetadata(CommandMessage.java:75)
            at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.encodeWithMetadata(RequestMessage.java:160)
            at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.encode(RequestMessage.java:147)
            at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.sendMessage(CommandHelper.java:88)
            at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32)
            at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:187)
            at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:135)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Aug 10, 2016 2:51:48 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
        INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server x.x.x.3:27017
        java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:53)
            at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:37)
            at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.getCodec(RequestMessage.java:245)
            at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.addDocument(RequestMessage.java:205)
            at com.mongodb.connection.CommandMessage.encodeMessageBodyWithMetadata(CommandMessage.java:75)
            at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.encodeWithMetadata(RequestMessage.java:160)
            at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.encode(RequestMessage.java:147)
            at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.sendMessage(CommandHelper.java:88)
            at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32)
            at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:187)
            at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:135)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am able to connect replica set form my local machine and some of my app servers. Ping is working fine form all app servers to DB servers.

Please help.

Thanks
NIkhil